# Rendering with gpu crashed

Tags: rendering, gpu, error

Does anyone know why this happened? I was rendering at 1000 samples on a gtx 1070 and the rendering crashed saying "CUDA error: Out of memory in cuCtxSynchronize(), line 1372" [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your GPU ran out of memory.
Try to reduce the number of individual Meshes and Texture sizes.

Comment: this worked but I had to restart blender before rerendering

Answer (score 0):

Yupp cuda error is Vram issue. Less particle effects, less things in general solves it. Getting a propper rig for what you want to achieve should be high on your next payday list of things to buy.