# Blender GPU rendering not working with the laptop charger plugged in

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

My laptop is Acer Nitro 5, intel i5 9300H, and GTX1650. Blender version is 3.1. GPU rendering setting is [CUDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P46GC.jpg) (screenshot). Nvidia driver version in 512.15, [here is a detailed paste](https://pastebin.com/jtqEDN6M).

I downloaded the famous bmw blender file. With the charger unplugged, I opened the gpu  blender file and clicked render, it renders the image perfectly.

Now this will drain the battery in no time.

Now, while rendering, if I plug in the charger, the rendering process crashes with the error,

```
Misaligned address in cuCtxSynchronize() (device_cuda_impl.cpp:1965)
```

Therefore I closed blender, Then I plugged in the charger, opened the bmw gpu blender file again, pressed render, this time also, I get the error,

```
Misaligned address in cuCtxSynchronize() (device_cuda_impl.cpp:1965)
```

I tried Optix setting too same result. I also tried blender 2.93, no dice.

What kind of sorcery is this? Why would my Laptop charging affect blender? How do I fix this?

EDIT : Solved on updating driver to 512.95 Still don't understand why charging affect GPU, power mode is already set to high performance with charger plugged in.

Comment: Maybe check your laptop's (windows) power management settings? It's possible (albeit unlikely) that your GPU accidentally got set to something like _low power_ or even _disabled_ when the charging cable is connected.

Comment: Laptop is set to high performance with charger plugged in.

Comment: This might sound strange, but try rendering when in solid view in the viewport - other users have reported that the GPU renders as normal so long as the scene is not in Rendered Preview mode (all other preview modes work). Next step is a d river full uninstall/reinstall, making sure to stay at a certain version - see here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208710/75504